# Simple Bootstrap 3 Thumbnail Gallery

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, gallery, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm trying to make a simple thumbnail gallery with text on the side. I'm looking to fit images in 6 columns and the text in the other 6 column so that the images are sitting on the left side of the text but in the same row. I can not figure this out.

My problem is that the images are being listed underneath each other rather than sitting like a normal gallery. What is going wrong?

Here my code

```
<div class="section">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-6">
        <a href="#" class="thumbnail"><img src="http://placehold.it/150x150" alt=""></a>
        <a href="#" class="thumbnail"><img src="http://placehold.it/150x150" alt=""></a>
        <a href="#" class="thumbnail"><img src="http://placehold.it/150x150" alt=""></a>
        <a href="#" class="thumbnail"><img src="http://placehold.it/150x150" alt=""></a>
        <a href="#" class="thumbnail"><img src="http://placehold.it/150x150" alt=""></a>
        <a href="#" class="thumbnail"><img src="http://placehold.it/150x150" alt=""></a>
      </div>

    <article class="col-md-6">
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Ab, ducimus harum distinctio nostrum similique nulla amet architecto expedita molestiae illum explicabo veritatis labore veniam a tempore consectetur error quod facilis.ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Ab, ducimus harum distinctio nostrum similique nulla amet architecto expedita molestiae illum explicabo veritatis labore veniam a tempore consectetur error quod facilis.ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Ab, ducimus harum distinctio nostrum similique nulla amet architecto expedita molestiae illum explicabo veritatis labore veniam a tempore consectetur error quod facilis.</p>

      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Ab, ducimus harum distinctio nostrum similique nulla amet architecto expedita molestiae illum explicabo veritatis labore veniam a tempore consectetur error quod facilis.ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Ab, ducimus harum distinctio nostrum similique nulla amet architecto expedita molestiae illum explicabo veritatis labore veniam a tempore consectetur error quod facilis.ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Ab, ducimus harum distinctio nostrum similique nulla amet architecto expedita molestiae illum explicabo veritatis labore veniam a tempore consectetur error quod facilis.</p>


    </article>

  </div>
</div>![bootstrap gallery][1]
```

Answer (score 2):

I think you want something like this to keep images in same row..

```
<div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-1"><a href="#" class="thumbnail"><img src="http://placehold.it/150x150" alt=""></a></div>
      <div class="col-md-1"><a href="#" class="thumbnail"><img src="http://placehold.it/150x150" alt=""></a></div>
      <div class="col-md-1"><a href="#" class="thumbnail"><img src="http://placehold.it/150x150" alt=""></a></div>
      <div class="col-md-1"><a href="#" class="thumbnail"><img src="http://placehold.it/150x150" alt=""></a></div>
      <div class="col-md-1"><a href="#" class="thumbnail"><img src="http://placehold.it/150x150" alt=""></a></div>
      <div class="col-md-1"><a href="#" class="thumbnail"><img src="http://placehold.it/150x150" alt=""></a></div>
      <article class="col-md-6">
      ..
      </article>
    </div>
```

http://bootply.com/94880

Comment: This is a correct answer, but a bit weird because the 'thumbnail' class doesn't do anything besides adding a border... The whole concept of the 'thumbnail' seems redundant.